# Decryption fails after appending to a file encrypted with a crypto stream

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

Hoping you can help out here. I'm creating a file an appending lines to this file using a Crypto stream.
If I write out all the lines at once then the file will encrypt/decrypt correctly.
But if I open the file in append mode, append a line, close then file. Then only the 1st line decrypts correctly, the other lines return back rubbish.

I am wondering if this is the correct behaviour. I'm trying to build up a text file of encrypted details users enter over the course of a day; and then batch processing them at the end of a day.
The overhead of decrypting and encrypting the whole file just to add a single line to it would seem to be excessive as I could end up with 1000's of lines over the course of a day.

I'm using the excact same Crypto Provider with the same Initialisaion Vector and key on all access to the file?

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to append to an encrypted file?

Cheers
Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. One thing you can do is encrypt each record (text line) separately AND add a prefix that indicates beginning of the block and it's length. Then when reading from the file, read the prefix, check the record length and load the record. Repeat for each record.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, that makes sense, I'll go ahead a work on that then.

Comment: I encrypted each block and Base64 Encoded it and wrote it out to the file a line at a time and that did do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the crypto you're using is a stream or chained cipher - meaning the output from one encrypted block is used to modify the next block. Directly appending to this kind of data and then attempting to decrypt the lot will not work because the dependency between the blocks will be broken.

A simple way to fix it is to add a marker or save some data for the offset+length of each record in the file. When you come to do the batch processing, you'll need to reset the CryptoProvider for each record.